# Virtual box multiple adapter settings issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, xubuntu

In virtual-box i have 2 VM's which has `Xubuntu` in one and `Ubuntu Server` in the other.

I have selected 2 Adapters in Network settings `'NAT'` and `'Host-only Adapter'`.

**Issue:**
Xubuntu gets correctly 2 network interfaces, where Ubuntu server is getting only one.

**OS -> XUBUNTU**

```
Settings -> Network
Adapter 1 -> NAT
Adapter 2 -> Host-only Adapter
```

**Result:**

```
eth0 : 10.0.2.15
eth1 : 192.168.56.102
```

**OS -> Ubuntu Server**

```
Settings -> Network
Adapter 1 -> NAT
Adapter 2 -> Host-only Adapter
```

**Result:**

```
eth0 : 10.0.2.15
```

For ubuntu server im not getting eth1 where i'm getting it for Xubuntu

**> ifconfig eth1**

```
eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:92:ad:7f
BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

/etc/network/interface

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address:    192.168.56.102
broadcast:  192.168.56.255
netmask:    255.255.255.0
gateway:    0.0.0.0
```

Comment: In Networking: Advanced and Change the Adaptor type. does that help?

Comment: For Ubuntu server, did you update /etc/network/interfaces? How about command output `ifconfig eth1`?

Comment: @RaymondTau, I have edited my question with ifconfig eth1 result

Comment: @sravis, then I would suspect you need to add something similar to `eth0` for `eth1` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

If that still doesn't work, please provide content of `/etc/network/interfaces` as well.

Comment: @RaymondTau i manually added static ip for eth1, now i got the ip, but internet doesn't work inside this vm. If i comment the eth1 then internet works fine inside this vm. I have updated my question.

Comment: @sravis, you should either set a correct gateway for eth1 or don't set it. Also, the `iface eht1` should be `iface eth1` instead. And you should not have two hosts with the same IP address.

Comment: @RaymondTau commenting gateway 0.0.0.0 worked out!! Thank you very much.. :-)